# Sinatra - Multiple public directories

Tags: ruby, sinatra, public

I'd like to link to a CSS and JavaScript files outside of the default public directory that Sinatra sets up.

I know I can use `set :public` to change the directory, but I want to retain the default directory along with the other 'public_2'.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sinatra does not allow multiple public dirs. Is there a specific reason why you need 2 public directories?  Is there some logic which files reside in which directory (e.g. 1 contains image, the other javascript files, ...)? Or do you wish for some sort of merged contents, i.e. a file may reside in any of the 2 dirs and sinatra should transparently serve the file?

Comment: I want to bolt-on some code that will run with the main application, but also be removable if required. At present I am including the files required to run the included files within the main application.rb

I know I could simply include the CSS in the main public folder, but  that's not something I want to do if I can avoid it.

As for logic - the 'public_2' folder would contain css, images and js directories just like in the normal public one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`TryStatic` middleware from rack-contrib](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/master/lib/rack/contrib/try_static.rb):

```
require 'rack/contrib/try_static'

use Rack::TryStatic, :root => 'public_2', :urls => %w[/]
```

Now the `public` and `public_2` directories will both be searched for files that match the request (`public_2` will be searched first, since the `TryStatic` middleware will be hit before the app itself).